# How to filter the result of a query based upon items in a list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

On my website, I have a search function. When a user wants to search, an object is created, which holds the search criteria. It looks like this:

```
public class SearchJSON : ISearchObject
{
    public List<String> sites { get; set; }
    public int minWage { get; set; }
    public int maxWage { get; set; }
    public List<String> countries { get; set; }
    public int minRating { get; set; }
    public int maxRating { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
    public List<String> skills { get; set; }

}
```

My applications database structure, classes and their relationships:

[image]

There is a function that queries the database and retrieves a list of Freelancers, based upon the search criteria that the user entered:

```
    var query = db.Freelancers
                   .Include("Skills").Include("Countries")
                   .Where(x => x.HourWageMin >= data.minWage)
                   .Where(x => x.HourWageMax <= data.maxWage)
                   .Where(x => x.Stars >= data.minRating)
                   .Where(x => x.Stars <= data.maxRating)
                   .Where(x => x.Countries != null && data.countries.Contains(x.Countries.Name));
```

The problem is I would like to filter out those who don't have Skills which are in the "`skills`" list of the `SearchJSON` object. How would i do this with my lambda expression?

Comment: @Kenci - Have you tried something like this: .Where(x => x.Skills.Any(s => data.skills.Contains(s.Name)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = db.Freelancers
               .Include("Skills").Include("Countries")
               .Where(x => x.HourWageMin >= data.minWage)
               .Where(x => x.HourWageMax <= data.maxWage)
               .Where(x => x.Stars >= data.minRating)
               .Where(x => x.Stars <= data.maxRating)
               .Where(x => x.Countries != null && data.countries.Contains(x.Countries.Name))
               .Where(x => x.Skills.Any(s => data.skills.Contains(s.Name)));
```

Sample test returning two freelancers:

```
internal void Run()
{
    //Seed();
    List<string> skills = new List<string>() { "Skill 1", "Skill 2" };
    var query = context.Freelancers
            .Include("Skill")
            .Where(x => x.Skill.Any(s => skills.Contains(s.Name)));
    // query returns two freelancers, 1 and 3.
}

private void Seed()
{

    Skill s1 = new Skill() { Name = "Skill 1" };
    Skill s2 = new Skill() { Name = "Skill 2" };
    Skill s3 = new Skill() { Name = "Skill 3" };
    Skill s4 = new Skill() { Name = "Skill 4" };
    Skill s5 = new Skill() { Name = "Skill 5" };
    Skill s6 = new Skill() { Name = "Skill 6" };

    Freelancer f1 = new Freelancer() { Name = "Freelancer 1" };
    f1.Skill.Add(s1);
    f1.Skill.Add(s3);
    f1.Skill.Add(s4);
    f1.Skill.Add(s6);

    Freelancer f2 = new Freelancer() { Name = "Freelancer 2" };
    f2.Skill.Add(s4);
    f2.Skill.Add(s6);

    Freelancer f3 = new Freelancer() { Name = "Freelancer 3" };
    f3.Skill.Add(s1);
    f3.Skill.Add(s6);

    Freelancer f4 = new Freelancer() { Name = "Freelancer 4" };
    f4.Skill.Add(s5);

    context.Freelancers.Add(f1);
    context.Freelancers.Add(f2);
    context.Freelancers.Add(f3);
    context.Freelancers.Add(f4);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Which generates this sql query:

```
{SELECT 
[Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project2].[Country_Id] AS [Country_Id], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project2].[Name1] AS [Name1]
FROM ( SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Country_Id] AS [Country_Id], 
[Join1].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Join1].[Name] AS [Name1], 
CASE WHEN ([Join1].[Skill_Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[Freelancers] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[Skill_Id] AS [Skill_Id], [Extent2].[Freelancer_Id] AS [Freelancer_Id], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM  [dbo].[SkillFreelancer] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Skills] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent2].[Skill_Id] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Join1].[Freelancer_Id]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[SkillFreelancer] AS [Extent4]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Skills] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent5].[Id] = [Extent4].[Skill_Id]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent4].[Freelancer_Id]) AND ([Extent5].[Name] IN (N'Skill 1',N'Skill 2'))
)
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[Id] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC}
```

Comment: Thanks this works but is pretty slow on 50K freelancers :P

Comment: Ye, I would have guessed that :p

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want eager loading? If no, go for lazy loading and write something like

```
db.Freelancers.Where( f => f.Skills.Where(s => s.Name == data.Name).Any()).ToList();
```

Now if you can't use lazy loading you can use explicit loading like below

```
db.Freelancers
   .Collection(p => p.Skills)
   .Query()
   .Where(u => u.Name.StartsWith("B"))
   .Load();
```

So far I don't think you can achieve what you want with the include(string).